# Subclassing a set of inter-dependent classes in Objective-C and ensuring type-safety

Tags: objective-c, overriding, abstract-class

I've implemented a basic **graph class** (not as in "plotting" but as in "network"!), that's to be used for **basic graph theoretical tasks**. *(see summarised header file snippets below)*

In addition to the **generic graph functionality** it also implements **functionality for node positioning in 3D space**. **And this extended 3D functionality I'd like to isolate into a subclass**, resulting in:

- light-weight generic classes `(MyGenericGraph,
  MyGenericGraphNode, MyGenericGraphEdge)`
- heavier-weight specialized subclasses
  `(My3DGraph, My3DGraphNode,
  My3DGraphEdge)`

So far so good, in theory, that is.

### Problem:

I'd have to ensure (and preferably at compile time) that one cannot add generic `MyGenericGraphNodes` to the spezialized `My3DGraph`, as it highly depends on the added 3D logic inside `My3DGraphNode`. (While the generic `MyGenericGraph` would simply not care.)

The core issue is as simple as this: I cannot override these methods from MyGenericGraph:

```
- (void)addNode:(MyGenericGraphNode *)aNode;
- (void)removeNode:(MyGenericGraphNode *)aNode;
```

with these methods in my subclass My3DGraph:

```
- (void)addNode:(My3DGraphNode *)aNode;
- (void)removeNode:(My3DGraphNode *)aNode;
```

I've so far come up with three possible solutions but before going for any of them I'd like to hear some opinions on them. (and hopefully spare me some unforeseen troubles on my way)

I'm wondering if there's **another and superior solution or design pattern** to this that I'm missing? **Or if not: which of my solutions would you go for?**
I'd love to hear your opinion on this.

### Possible solution 1

- **Adding an abstract class** `MyAbstractGraph` that would basically be **identical to the generic parts of my current implementation** of `MyGenericGraph` (see below), but would **lack any node-addition/removal methods**. `MyGenericGraph` **and** `My3DGraph` **would then simply be subclasses of** `MyAbstractGraph`. And while `MyGenericGraph` would only implement the lacking node-addition/removal methods, `My3DGraph` would further more implement all 3D space functionality. Both requiring their respective node class types. (same for `MyGenericGraphNode` and `MyGenericGraphEdge` and their 3D counterparts)

**Problems with this solution:** It would **add a significant amount of complexity** to an otherwise **rather simple problem**.
Further more as `My3DGraph` should be able to deal with `My3DGraphNodes` AND `MyGenericGraphNodes`, I'd have to implement `MyGenericGraph`'s method as:

```
- (void)addNode:(MyAbstractGraphNode *)aNode;`
```

but `My3DGraph`'s method as:

```
- (void)addNode:(My3DGraphNode *)aNode;
```

as well, as otherwise my generic graph it wouldn't accept 3d nodes. This would expose the abstract class unnecessarily though.

### Possible solution 2

**True and simple subclasses + moving** `MyGenericGraphNode/My3DGraphNode` **allocation right into** `MyGenericGraph/My3DGraph`, to get something like: `- (MyGenericGraphNode *)newNode;`, which would **allocate and return a node** of correct type **and add it to the graph** right away. One would then **get rid of** `- (void)addNode:(MyGenericGraphNode *)aNode;` entirely, **leaving no chance to add nodes than from within the Graph itself** (hence assuring proper class membership).

**Problems with this solution:** While it would not add any noteworthy complexity to the classes, it would on the other hand basically get me into the same predicament again, as soon as I—let's say—wanted to add functionality to my `My3DGraph` for moving a node from one graph to another. And imho a class should be able to deal with an object no matter who created it and why.

### Possible solution 3

**True and simple subclasses + adding specialized method for 3D nodes and disabling generic method**, like so:

```
- (void)addNode:(MyGenericGraphNode *)aNode {
    [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd];
}

- (void)add3DNode:(My3DGraphNode *)aNode {
    //bla
}
```

**Problems with this solution:** The generic `[a3DGraph addNode:aNode]` method would still show up in Xcode's auto-complete, pass silently on compile, but unexpectedly throw exception on run. Frequent headaches foreseen.

### Possible solution 4

**True and simple subclasses for my graph and just the generic classes for node and edge, but with an additional ivar pointer `My3DUnit *dimensionalUnit:` in node class (defaulting to nil for MyGraph) that implements all the logic and properties and provides 3D functionality to the node class.** `My3DUnit` can simply be silently created (with position (0,0,0) e.g.) and attached to generic nodes in case they get added to a 3d graph, and hence made compatible. Vice versa if a node with a `DL3DUnit`gets added to a generic graph it simply keeps it attached and adds the node.

### Header Files

Here are the (shortened) headers of my classes:

```
@interface MyGraph : NSObject {
    // properties:
    NSMutableSet *nodes;
    //...

    //extended 3D properties:
double gravityStrength;
    //...
}
// functionality:
- (void)addNode:(MyGraphNode *)aNode;
- (void)removeNode:(MyGraphNode *)aNode;
//...

//extended 3D functionality:
- (double)kineticEnergy;
//...

@end

@interface MyGraphNode : NSObject { 
    // properties:
    MyGraph *graph;
    NSMutableSet *edges;
    //...

    //extended 3D properties:
    My3DVector position;
    //...
}
// properties:
@property (nonatomic, readonly) MyGraph *graph;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSSet *edges;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSSet *neighbors;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSUInteger degree;
//...

//extended 3D properties
@property (nonatomic, assign) My3DVector position;
//...

// functionality:
- (void)attachToGraph:(MyGraph *)aGraph;
- (void)detachFromGraph;
- (void)addNeighbor:(MyGraphNode *)aNode;
- (void)removeNeighbor:(MyGraphNode *)aNode;
- (BOOL)hasNeighbor:(MyGraphNode *)aNode;
- (NSSet *)neighbors;
- (NSUInteger)degree;
//...

//extended 3D functionality:
- (double)distanceToNode:(DLGraphNode *)aNode;
//...

@end

@interface MyGraphEdge : NSObject {
    // properties:
    MyGraphNode *predecessor;
    MyGraphNode *successor;
    //...
}

// properties:
@property (nonatomic, readonly) MyGraphNode *predecessor;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) MyGraphNode *successor;
//...

// functionality:
- (id)initWithPredecessorNode:(MyGraphNode *)predecessorNode successorNode:(MyGraphNode *)successorNode;
+ (MyGraphEdge *)edgeWithPredecessorNode:(MyGraphNode *)predecessorNode successorNode:(MyGraphNode *)successorNode;
- (BOOL)hasNeighbor:(MyGraphNode *)aNode;
- (BOOL)hasSuccessor:(MyGraphNode *)aNode;
- (BOOL)hasPredecessor:(MyGraphNode *)aNode;

@end
```

*This is basically how my graph is implemented right now. There's obviously quite a bunch more to it, but you should get the idea.*

(As you might have noticed MyGenericGraphEdge currently implements no 3D space functionality, but it might in the future, like computing its center point, e.g., hence I've included it here.)

[Edit: Added solution 4 inspired by ughoavgfhw; fixed a mistake in solution 1, sorry for that :(]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution, quick and dirty:

After re-analysing my class structure and finding several **previously unforeseen implications** on **potential pitfalls in future development** on my planned graph class family I've come to the conclusion to **go pretty much with my proposed solution 4 but accompany it by some major restructuring** (see attached simplified ER diagram). My plan is to **instead of having heavy multi-purpose über-classes, have several single-purpose components** that (if well constructed) can be **combined into various kinds of special-purpose** (and relatively lightweight) **toolsets**.

### Potential pitfalls of simple inheritance:

If I implement dimensional feature sets in a subclass of `MyGenericGraph`, then this **makes it basically impossible for me to easily create more specific graph subclasses** (for specialized trees e.g.) that can be either lightweight and generic (like `MyGenericGraph`) or dimensional (like `My3DGraph`). For a `MyGenericTree` class (for tree analysis e.g.) I'd have to subclass `MyGenericGraph`. For a `My3DTree` (for tree display e.g.) however I'd have to subclass `My3DGraph`. `My3DTree` could therefor not inherit any logic from `MyGenericTree`. I'd have implement the dimensional features redundantly. Bad. Pretty bad.

### Proposed class structure architectures:

- **Get rid of any "dimensional flavored" classes** entirely. Keep **classes strictly barebones data structures** with just the basic and required logic.
- **Introduce MyVertex class that provides dimensional attributes & methods** to nodes if required (By adding a `MyVertex *vertex` ivar to `MyGraphNode` (defaulting to nil)). This also makes it much **easier to re-use them in `MyVertexCloud`**, a simple point cloud container, that should come in handy for improving my force-driven layout algorithm.
- **Delegate any logic that's not strictly essential** to the graphs' data-structure **to special purpose helper classes**. **As such `MyGraphNodeClusterRelaxer` will be responsible for any logic specific to visual graph layout.**
- **Subclassing `MyGraph` will be quick and easy** thanks to my **single-chained inheritance** chain and **modularity**.
- **Utilizing an external `MyGraphNodeClusterRelaxer` will also allow me to relax a subset of graph nodes**, not just an entire graph, as My3DGraph would have done it.
- `MyGraphNodeCluster` will be nothing more than a wrapper for basically a set of nodes (all of the same graph). **Subclasses of it can be more specific in cluster membership criteria and algorithms.**
- **Getting a `MyGraphNodeCluster` from an entire graph will be** as **easy** as calling `(MyGraphNodeCluster *)[myGraph nodeCluster];` and from there you get a `MyVertexCloud` via `(MyVertexCloud *)[myNodeCluster vertexCloud];`. *The reverse (for the latter) is not possible for obious reasons.*

### (Simplified) Entity Relational Model:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Personally I wouldn't use any of these. I was going to suggest something similar to your second solution as an alternative, but I think this is a better way to it:

Declare addNode as `- (void)addNode:(MyGenericGraphNode *)node`. Then, in the implementation, make sure it is the right class. This is an even better choice since you mentioned in the **problems with solution 1** section that you wanted the 3D graph to handle generic nodes too. I don't know how you want to handle them, but you could detect that the new node was not 3D and create a new 3D node from it, such as by just setting the z coordinate to 0 for everything.

Example:

```
//My3DGraph implementation
- (void)addNode:(MyGenericGraphNode *)node {
    if(![node isKindOfClass:[My3DGraphNode class]])
        node = [My3DGraphNode nodeWithNode:node];
    //add node
}

//My3DGraphNode class
+ (My3DGraphNode *)nodeWithNode:(MyGenericGraphNode *)otherNode {
    //Make sure you can create a 3D node from otherNode
    //Change 2D properties of otherNode to 3D properties, create new node with those properties
}
```

Comment: ughoavgfhw, thanks for your answer. (I had a mistake in solution 2, sorry about that, fixed. Snippet contradicted my text) Anyway, regarding your proposed solution:
If you consider this potential usage: http://pastie.org/private/avmzet8o4bctdz0sb8zwa (sorry, code wouldn't have fit into comment), you'll agree, I think, that while being simple it bears a huge potential for misbehaving, yet successfully compiling (and not even exception throwing) code.
A method that claims to be adding a node to a graph, but then without notice decides to silently add a copy of it instead, is utterly error prone.

Comment: @Regexident I see what you mean. I also see that you added a fourth possibility, which is about what I was about to suggest. Except I was going to say that basically the public classes are just wrappers which pass calls to internal classes, and the type of internal class used in a given node could be changed to change the type of the external node. Then, the class used to allocate node would just determine what class is initially used internally. Basically a proxy-based class cluster.

Comment: Looks like I've found a solution that should work pretty well (with a bit of solution 4 in it). See my own answer. Thanks for your answer though! Much appreciated.